# Rails/Ruby: don't understand this method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm reading a book called RailsAntiPatterns. In the `converter` method below, a new `OrderConverter` object is instantiated, and I assume `self` refers to an instance of `Order` class.

```
# app/models/order.rb
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  def converter 
    OrderConverter.new(self)
  end 

end

# app/models/order_converter.rb 
class OrderConverter

  attr_reader :order 

  def initialize(order)
    @order = order 
  end

  def to_xml # ...
  end

  def to_json # ...
  end

  def to_csv # ...
  end

  def to_pdf # ...
  end 
end
```

1. Why instantiate a new class inside of converter?
2. Why does `self` need to be passed as an argument?
3. Can you summarize in lay terms what's going on?

Comment: In the future, please post nicely formatted code. It can mean the difference between no answers and many answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why instantiate a new class inside of converter?

Of course, it's up to the choice of the author, but it's probably convenient. For instance:

```
@my_order = Order.new 
@my_order.converter.to_xml
```

That reads quite nicely, which is important in the eyes of a Rubyist. As the original designer of Ruby, Yukihiro Matsumoto (Matz) has [said](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_%28programming_language%29#Philosophy):

> But in fact we need to focus on humans, on how humans care about doing programming or operating the application of the machines. We are the masters. They are the slaves.

Readibility for humans is, therefore, important if you wish to produce elegant Ruby code.

> Why does "self" need to be passed as an argument?

Quite simply, OrderConverter requires an order to convert. Since the method `converter` is defined for instances of the Order class, an instance that wishes to convert itself will pass `self` as the argument to OrderConverter#new.

> can you summarize in lay terms what's going on?

I hope the above has done that for you.

Answer (score 1):

There's not much happening here.

```
def converter 
  OrderConverter.new(self)
end
```

this method creates a new `OrderConverter` and returns it. `OrderConverter` is passed a reference to the `Order` (`self`) that it can use to do its work (converting).

That's basically it.

Comment: in the question, I asked "why" twice. You explain "what" happens. Thanks for answering, but it doesn't really clarify the "why" for me. Well, you do sort of explain "why" a little (that it can use to do its work).

Comment: As for the first "why": it has to be created somewhere. Why not in this method?

Comment: I was thinking "why" as in "what benefits does it bring". For example, I think he can now call order.converter.to_pdf.  So I guess the benefit is chaining?

Comment: There's no chaining in `order.converter.to_pdf`, that's a different concept.

Answer (score 1):

he's *returning* a new instance of OrderConverter whenever you call the instance method "converter" from the Order class (it's an implicit return).

the constructor from OrderConverter takes an instance of Order as its first argument.

regarding the "why" questions, there's no real answer as far as Ruby is concerned, it's up to the implementator -i.e. the author- what the code actually does.